# Java regex for optionally enclosed csv-string returns unexpected results

Tags: java, regex

In Java I have a string (taken from a csv-file):

```
40;"blue-collar";"married";"secondary";"no";1100;"yes";"no";"unknown";29;"may";660
```

My class `CSV_Worker` will split it by the given delimiter (`;`) and removes the quotation marks if necessary:

```
public class CSV_Worker {

  Pattern pattern = null;
  int colCount = -1;

  public CSV_Worker (String delimiter, int colCount) {
    // (?<=^|;)(?:"([^;]*)"|([^;]*))(?=;|$)
    this.pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\" + delimiter + ")(?:\"([^\\" + delimiter + "]*)\"|([^\\" + delimiter + "]*))(?=\\" + delimiter + "|$)");
    this.colCount = colCount;
  }

  public String [] split (String line) {

    String [] result = new String[this.colCount];
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    int idx = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
      result[idx] = m.group();
      idx++;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Why does `CSV_Worker.split(myString)` return

```
40
"blue-collar"
"married"
...
```

instead of

```
40
blue-collar
married
...
```

?

**Edit**

thanks to @Fabian the solution was another regexp:

```
(?<=^|\|)"?((?<!")[^\|]*(?!")|(?<=")[^"]*(?="))"?(?=\||$)
```

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wQVwWD0KIRr-nCkO)

Comment: Try `String[] result = line.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").split("\"?;\"?");`.

Comment: basically a good idea but the quotation-marks are not Independent of each other. The string might contain an element with a leading/trailing quotation-mark only, this has to remain in the result.

Comment: Don't try to parse CSV data using regex. Use a CSV parser. That's what they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `m.group()` you get the whole match (i.e. group 0), not just the content of one of the capturing groups. This includes the quotes from your non-capturing group. Furthermore you use different capturing groups for the case where there are quotes and the case there are no quotes. You therefore need to use the `Matcher` like this:

```
String g1 = m.group(1);
result[idx] = (g1 == null ? m.group(2) : g1);
```

---

You could also use just a single capturing group by using lookarounds

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\" + delimiter + ")\"?((?<!\")[^\\" + delimiter + "]*(?!\")|(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"))\"?(?=\\" + delimiter + "|$)");
```

which allows you to use

```
result[idx] = m.group(1);
```

in the split method instead.

Comment: smart, thank you for that. I used the 2nd solution since it is faster.

Comment: btw: Your solutions becomes perfect if the positive lookaround (2nd part in or) is replaced by `(?<=\")[^"]*(?=\")`. It now Matches elems like `...;"afw;e22";...` as well